# Why matplotlib cannot plot multiple lines on the same graph?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, quantconnect

I am using an online backtesting platform Quantconnect which use jupyter as their research environment.

I have the following codes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
expiry_range = [180, 360]#, 540, 720]
for upper in expiry_range:
    data = getAllOptionChains(symbols, -200, 200, upper-30, upper, datetime(2020, 1, 16, 10, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 16, 10, 11))
    clean = data[data['S/E'] <1.2]
    clean = clean.sort_values('S/E')
    params, params_covariance = curve_fit(func,np.asarray(clean['S/E']).astype(np.float64), np.asarray(clean['W/E']).astype(np.float64))
    #ax.scatter(np.asarray(clean['S/E']).astype(np.float64), np.asarray(clean['W/E']).astype(np.float64))
    ax.plot(np.asarray(clean['S/E']).astype(np.float64), func(np.asarray(clean['S/E']).astype(np.float64), params[0], params[1]))
```

I tried to plot 2 lines on the same graph. But I can only see one line in the plot. What have I done wrong?

This is the plot I got

[image: The plot I have]

A sample of the data `clean`

```
  expiry                     symbol          W/E        S/E
26 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59VEMBEQU|UVXY 2T  0.000864865  0.0577838
24 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UN03NNQ|UVXY 2T  0.000277778  0.0593889
23 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59VCYS292|UVXY 2T  0.000914286  0.0610857
21 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UMU5BLY|UVXY 2T   0.00635294  0.0628824
20 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59VBB8PRA|UVXY 2T   0.00545455  0.0647879
18 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UMO6ZK6|UVXY 2T    0.0046875  0.0668125
17 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V9NPD9I|UVXY 2T   0.00483871  0.0689677
15 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UMI8NIE|UVXY 2T  0.000933333  0.0712667
14 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V8060RQ|UVXY 2T   0.00344828  0.0737241
12 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UMCABGM|UVXY 2T   0.00535714  0.0763571
11 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V6CMO9Y|UVXY 2T   0.00555556  0.0791852
9  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UM6BZEU|UVXY 2T   0.00384615  0.0822308
8  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V4P3BS6|UVXY 2T        0.006    0.08552
6  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UM0DND2|UVXY 2T   0.00416667  0.0890833
5  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V31JZAE|UVXY 2T   0.00156522  0.0929565
3  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59ULUFBBA|UVXY 2T   0.00454545  0.0971818
2  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59V1E0MSM|UVXY 2T   0.00104762    0.10181
0  2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UK6Y3ZA|UVXY 2T      0.00395     0.1069
64 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UZQHAAU|UVXY 2T   0.00789474   0.112526
62 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59ULIIN7Q|UVXY 2T   0.00833333   0.118778
61 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UY2XXT2|UVXY 2T   0.00588235   0.125765
59 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59ULCKB5Y|UVXY 2T      0.00925   0.133625
58 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UWFELBA|UVXY 2T   0.00473333   0.142533
56 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UL6LZ46|UVXY 2T   0.00507143   0.152714
55 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UURV8TI|UVXY 2T   0.00584615   0.164462
53 2020-06-19  UVXY XFH59UL0NN2E|UVXY 2T   0.00533333   0.178167
17 2020-06-19        I XFH59UQH2JJA|I 2T    0.0025641   0.181795
```

Comment: Can you include the plot this is giving you and some of the data?

Comment: @gboffi I have put the `plt.plot` into a loop. Will that plot 2 lines for me?

Comment: Is `plt.show()` inside the `for loop`? if yes it should be outside the loop to show all the lines

Comment: @joe yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write `plt.show()` outside the `for loop` to show all the lines